# How secure a method should be?

Tags: javascript

As I am writing some code, I am wondering how secure my methods should be. Should I trust the user of my class ? Or check everything ? This implies parameters type checking which may not be a good practice as Javascript is supposed to be duck typed.

Basically this leads to the question of trust. Is there a best practice ? Is there an implicit "contract" ?

Example :

```
CarsCollection.prototype.get = function ( index ) {
    return this.collection[index];
};
```

Or

```
CarsCollection.prototype.get = function ( index ) {
    var self = this;

    if ( ! index ) {
        throw new ReferenceError();
    }

    if ( isNaN ( index ) ) {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    return self.collection[index];
};
```

Comment: Be as paranoid as possible. Trust no one, especially yourself.

Comment: Interesting question. In languages that do play on private/public/protected modifiers it is usually public -> check everything you can, private/protected -> relax; but since there is everything public for javascript ..

Answer (score 1):

In general things like framework code and reusable libraries are the prime candidate for extensive argument checking because you (and your current and future colleagues) going to use this code a lot.

You don't have to add argument checks *everywhere*, just use them when it's sensible.

If you want to specify certain behaviour like: *should `array_delete_value` modify the input argument or return a copy with the value removed?* Specify it in the comments and add a test that tests for exactly this behaviour.

If you're worried about performance you can write assert-like statements and remove them in your minification step. This is analogous to compiling with asserts off.

Asserts could look like:

```
argument("index", index).of_type("number").required();
```

---

If you downvoted, could you please leave a comment. Did I miss something? Do you have a competing methodology?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I'm curious about that assert example you posted. Do you have an example of a library with an api like that or is this just an idea?

Comment: It's a custom library I have and am using (for over 2 years now). As you would have guessed it's a fluent API. You could add functions like `.is_instanceof` and `.not_null`. It helps to have a well defined duck-typing checker, even for simple cases like `object` and `array`. Is an `array` an `object`? What about a `promise`? How do you deal with `DOMNodes` and other native objects?

Comment: With the closure library you can add as many assert statements as you like. Then have the closure compiler strip them out when you compress your code. That's how I do it.

Comment: That seems like a nice solution. Keep in mind though that `asserts` are not natively supported yet in all browsers. The library I have is also more powerful than just `assert(/* must be true*/);`.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen [This is the library](http://brevvi-closure.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_asserts_asserts.js.html) I make extensive use of. I guess any browser incompatibilities are abstracted away.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find out how robust your methods are by **unit testing** them. If you write good tests, you'll quickly find that your methods need to be able to handle all kinds of wack input.

It is up to you how far you want to go, but to be clear: **don't just assume that the inputs will be valid**.

Personally, I validate the hell out of anything that is coming from another class/module/whatever, even if its not third party. You need to make sure that the entry points to each module are robust. I relax *a little more* within a given class/module, but still make sure to validate enough to prevent errors.

In your sample code, it looks like other pieces of code outside of `CarsCollection` will be calling the `get` method. So, you'll want to validate index for sure.

Comment: Actually, this question came up while I was unit testing my methods.

Comment: @Simon nice! So then you are probably also wondering how viciously you should unit test your methods. I'd say that the same reasoning from my answer and Frits's answer apply to that question.

Answer (score 0):

I like to make my code as dummy-proof as possible. This reduces the number of WTF's elicited by developers using my API/function/code. Argument-checking is always a good practice, especially in a dynamically-typed language like JavaScript. So there is nothing wrong with what you are doing. Type checking is permissible in JavaScript also. I find it easier to keep track of a function that explicitly states the types of its arguments. This lessens the cognitive load on the user of your API (i.e., not having to deal with `foo(5)` and `foo("5")`) and *also* lessens your own cognitive-load when you are writing the function since you won't have to deal with the idiosyncrasies of JavaScript's types and can be sure that an argument *is* the type that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't exactly answer your question, it's important to note that the looseness of javascript makes many of your issues a non-issue (unless you want them to be).

- If index is falsey, and you look at collection[index], you'll simply get `undefined`.  I'm honestly not sure if that's a feature of arrays/objects or if the falsey value got coerced to a 0, but either way, it's not officially an error.
- If index is not a number, the bracket notation will fall back from looking for an array member to an object property.  In the worst case, it will return `undefined`, but in the best case, you can use the dynamic capabilities of objects to your advantage.
- Realize that your current check will fail on CarsCollection.get(0), since 0 is falsey.
- Also, isNaN handles if its parameter is null or undefined.

So neither of the things you check for are an error.  If it was a fatal error, JavaScript would throw an error itself.

Now, to the question itself, my opinion is that javascript is so loose and uncontained, that most checking is unnecessary.  If the using function passes bad parameters, the other programmer should figure out why.  It's not like you can hide your code from them.  The thing I value most is good documentation (check out [jsdoc](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/), then use it).  If you define your interface well, the programmer can use it.  That's just IMO, though.

Comment: Follow the **rule of least expectation**. I would expect `.get(null)` on a list-like object to throw an Error rather than return `undefined`.

Comment: It seems to me that Javascript only throws errors when it has to.  It's much more prone to returning `undefined` (and then throwing an error when you try to access a property of `undefined`).  Where else in javascript does a container throw an error?

Comment: If your expectation is that it returns null/undefined then that is fine (should it return null or undefined, does it matter?). My expectations are not your expectation, or that of your colleagues. Whoever, I would caution you to model your choices based off choices made in JavaScript because not all the parts are created equally elegant.

Comment: I can elaborate a little bit more on this. When you have an `array` there is a `length` property so you can check if `array[5]` will give you a good value or just always `undefined`. But in the DOM API there is no way of checking the existence of an element with a specific id so you will use `document.getElementById("myid") === null` (note that it returns `null`, not `undefined`). My opinion is that if you _can_ check (before hand) that a call is going to succeed you should throw an Error if it doesn't because it is **unexpected**. This is also why it's ok for `indexOf` to return `-1`.

Comment: But you can't be certain if array[5] is undefined based on the length.  As per the spec (page 122), it's perfectly valid to do: `var arr = []; arr.length = 10; console.log(arr.length); console.log(arr[5]);`. The results in the console would be `10`, then `undefined`.  I don't disagree with your claim for document.getElementById, but the spec for javascript containers (arrays and objects) is to not throw an error.

Comment: That's not what I said. What I said is: when `array.length` is 3 you know for sure `array[5]` is going to be `undefined`. You can't just turn that statement around ;) When `array.length` is 10 and `array[5]` is `undefined` then apparently you are expecting `undefined` and it's fine. `undefined` is just another value, it's fine to use it. You could argue that `array[5]` should throw an Error when the `length` is 3 and I would say: it probably should.

Comment: We're splitting hairs, and I hope you don't take offense by it.  Just to make sure we're unambiguous: array.length says nothing other than that any valid elements are below that length.  If the length reports 5, we do know that array[5] and above will be undefined, and that array[0]-array[4] may or may not be undefined (i.e. sparse arrays are allowed).  In any case, array[whatever] always returns something and doesn't throw an error.